# Handle OTP using a REST API call

Tags: rest, totp

I'm developing a new web page that is public facing. When the user hits the web page, they are prompted to enter their phone# and email id and click submit. An OTP is generated by the server and sent via sms to the phone# and another OTP is sent to the email id. Each OTP record in the database is associated with an otp id and the otp number(for lack of a better word)
The user is next prompted to enter both OTPs(the otp numbers) and click the validate button.

I don't want to send the phone#, emailid and otp number entered by the user on the same POST request(not using GET due to security reasons) for validation since that would not be very secure.
Hence I was considering sending the otp id(saved as a hidden field on the form) & otp number on the POST request for validation. Does anybody see any security related issues with this?

Comment: If you care about security, why are you using SMS-based OTP at all? SMS-based auth is very insecure.

Comment: This project is for an NGO that has little funding and only 1 resource.  Hence I cannot go for a sophisticated solution. I considered new user registration using a password, but I didn't go for that due to 2 reasons - a. These users will login to this site probably once or twice a year and will mostly not remember their password b. Building a password based solution requires me to handle all the password maintenance tasks(account locked, forgot password..) etc. Since I'm the only one available, I felt the OTP approach was the simplest and I tried to make it two factor by having 2 OTPs.

Comment: The other simple solution is Oauth2 based using their gmail id or meta id. If the id does not exist in the system, I can treat them as a new user else they will get treated as an existing user. There won't be a 2FA here unless the users configures it on gmail or meta.

Comment: Based on what you wrote - I think you should use primarily use Google federated auth and allow users to add a backup/alternative login with a traditional email+password. Applications shouldn't use OTP unless they actually _need it_ based on an evidence-based threat-model - so unless you're a bank - or if a compromised user-account could lead to significant harms/damage, it's best to avoid adding unneecssary hurdles for your users to jump through.

Comment: Thanks, Dai. Appreciate the help. I'll read up on Google federated auth and see if it works for us. The traditional login  + password is not doable for now due to the reasons I mentioned in my earlier message. I will surely look into it once the core application functionality has been productionalized.